# combineLatest for Single

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have a Single, and a Flowable. I want to do some action with the first value of the Flowable and the value of the Single. What operator do I use?

If this were two Observables or two Flowables, I'd use `combineLatest`, but I couldn't find a similar operator on Single or Maybe.

Comment: what about `Single.toObservable()` or `Single.toFlowable()` ?

Comment: That's the last resort. A Single operator is preferable

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer is `zipWith`, which does the combining for Single/Maybe

Comment: you will have only one emission, that's what you looking for ?

Comment: yes, in the question, I specify that I want to combine the single with the *first* value of Flowable